# STARS.Web.csproj' targets 'net471'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to publish a .csproj through the TFS Visual Studio Build task. When I Publish this project manually through Visual Studio 2017 it publishes correctly  and everything works.

However we I run the build definition through tfs I am getting the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>   (1656, 5) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1656,5):
>   Error : Project '..\STARS.Web\STARS.Web.csproj' targets 'net471'. It
>   cannot be referenced by a project that targets
>   '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.

What am I doing differently between the TFS Build Task and publishing manually through Visual Studio 2017. Is there any way to check the steps both these process are doing? Both use the same publish profile.

**TFS Build Definition Task:**

[image]

Comment: Have you try to build that project on the build server with Visual Studio 2017 directly? And what is the version of your Visual Studio on the build server? There is a similar issue, which fixed at 15.9 Preview 3. https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2274. Try to update your Visual Studio to latest version and republish it again.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I have updated the Visual Studio on the TFS server to 15.9.2 and tried to publish the project manually and worked fine. Running through TFS build definition still returns with the same error.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Could you reproduce this issue with new blank projects/solution? If yes, please share it via one driver, so that I could check it. Thanks.